# Can I limit AWS API keys to a specific EC2 instance (or even to a specific VPC)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a use-case where I would need to give the users the ability to use their assigned AWS API (i.e. not private API gateway) keys only from a specific EC2 host. Yes, a role assigned to the host might be better, but we need to be able to identify actions executed by a specific user (i.e. non-repudiation). Outside of that EC2 host (which is used to execute long-running ad-hoc jobs) MFA is enforced on a separate set of API keys each user holds. Because the nature of the ad-hoc jobs is undetermined, the idea was to basically deny access for those "in-instance" keys elsewhere while within the instance the users would have their normally assigned permissions.

But, this may not be possible to implement. I had first thought I'd use `aws:SourceIP` to identify the source, but of course, the VPC-internal IPs are non-routable and thus can be overlapped in other VPCs elsewhere. Then I thought perhaps `aws:SourceVpc` would work, but it only works with services that utilize private endpoints (like S3).

So, am I out of luck with this approach? Any other clever ideas on how I could limit a specific set of API keys to a specific EC2 instance (optimally), or to a specific VPC (better than nothing) using an IAM policy, regardless of what AWS API operations would be executed with those keys? (I.e. "deny everything unless on EC2 instance X")

Comment: I'm assuming that you're talking abut AWS IAM user credentials when you say "AWS API keys". What control are you hoping to achieve by restricting a given IAM user to executing AWS API calls from a specific EC2 instance? Why is this OK but executing the same calls, with the same credentials, from elsewhere is not OK?

Comment: Yes, IAM user credentials for the AWS public API. The goal would be to simply give the option for MFA-free operation for long-running executions. We are about to move to MFA-enforcement also for the `awscli` (i.e., not just the web console), and as the MFA session length will be soon limited to 1-2 hours, it will interfere with long user-executed operations that run hours, sometimes days. We're moving them to execution pipelines, but that project won't be complete for some time to come. I will have to see if the keys can be limited to specific services like S3 where `SourceVpc` could be used.

Comment: Perhaps you could route all outbound traffic from the EC2 instance through a NAT with an Elastic IP and then place a deny all condition in the IAM user policies if source IP is not the IP of that NAT.

Comment: Yes, that may be the only option, and it may be too much of a kludge to be acceptable. I suspect that unless the long-running usage can be limited to the AWS services which can be restricted to the VPC (e.g., S3), we'll end up using roles.